# Protractor getText of WebElement in repeater array

Tags: angularjs, protractor

In an html page I have:

```
<ul class="phones">
              <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy: orderProp">
                {{phone.name}} - {{phone.age}}
                <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

In an e2e test I have (is returning two elements in the array):

```
            var result= ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('phone in phones').column('phone.name'));

            result.then(function(arr) {
                arr[0].getText().then(function(text) {
                    console.log("*** 1: "+ text);
                });

                arr[1].getText().then(function(text) {
                    console.log("*** 2: "+ text);
                })
            });
```

The console is printing all three columns, phone.name, phone.age, and phone.snippet.
Why is the selector not just returning phone.name?

Its actually returning whatever I have in the list "li", plain text or a binding.

Comment: Should it be `.column('name')` as per examples here https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#writing-tests ?

Comment: No, that didn't do it, still coming back with all the text

Comment: One problem might be that protractor is trying to locate elements there and since the wrapping element for `phone.name` binding is `li`, its returning that. Maybe try with `.column('snippet')` and see if `p` is returned?

Comment: Great thought, you are right, selected 'snippet' only and only returned the snippet. So, I need to adjust my html accordingly? FYI...enter an answer not a comment and I'll vote check mark it appropriately, thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example tries to locate elements with the strategy below (column part is fixed as per comments):

```
protractor.By.repeater('phone in phones').column('name')
```

Repeater part matches the `li` element and then goes to find element(s) with `phone.name` binding. It's wrapping element happens to be the same `li`.

Changing column part to `.column('snippet')` returns `p` elements because `phone.snippet` binding is found inside of those.

Relevant docs/examples here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#writing-tests