# How to access input at item level in protractor by model

Tags: protractor

## Not Able to access angular input by protractor by model

Have been through [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988107/protractor-gettext-of-webelement-in-repeater-array)

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos">
  <!--i can access span-->
  <span>{{todo.text}}</span>
  <span>{{todo.address}}</span>
  <span>{{todo.done}}</span>

  <!--i CAN'T access input -->
  <input type="text" ng-model="todo.text"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="todo.address"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="todo.done"/>
</div>
```

Protractor Javasript I Can access Span At Item Level But Cannot access Input

```
var result= 
browser.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('todo in todos').column('todo.text'));

/*For Span at item level It works*/
/*
result.then(function(arr) {
   arr[0].getText().then(function(text) {
    console.log(": "+ text);
  });
});*/
```

For Input at item level It dosen't works

### Try 1 : typeError: Cannot call method 'getText' of undefined

```
/*
result.then(function(arr) {
   arr[0].getText().then(function(text) {
    console.log(": "+ text);  //TypeError: Cannot call method 'getText' of undefined
  });
});*/
```

### Try 2 : typeError : Cannot call method then of undefined

How to access model according to

### [How protractor access to model](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model)

```
result.then(function(arr) {
  arr[0].then(function(text) {
    console.log(": "+ text.getAttribute('value')); 

  });
});
```

Not Able to find What Wrong I Am doing ..Is There Any other way to access Angular input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying for a long time I was able to get this working:

```
element(by.repeater('todos')).evaluate('todos.length').then(function(itemLength)
{
    for(var i = 0 ; i < itemLength ; i++)
    {
        var result= element(by.repeater('todo in todos').row(i));

        result.then(function(arr)
        {                     
            /*FETCH TEXT*/
            var m = arr.all(by.model("todo.text")).getAttribute('value');
            m.then(function(l){
                console.log(l);
            });

            /*CLEAR TEXT*/
            arr.all(by.model("todo.text")).clear();

            /*SET TEXT*/
            arr.all(by.model("todo.text")).sendKeys('Hello');
        });
    };
});
```

Doubts :

1. I know about `Angular promise..then` .i have nested three `Angular promise..then` one inside another but don't know why use `then` in protractor.
2. Below "evaluate" just returns itemcount.

Comment: i tried to avoid by.css ,by.id ,by.classname and tried to do it in more (angular + protractor) way.though by.css ,by.id ,by.classname are also part of protractor api but by going through by.model i had to write less code.and understand a bit

Comment: I removed the part about "Is this the best approach to access angular model properties? Is this their standard way? I saw several other examples accessing angular model rudely." If you have another problem, please ask it in a separate question.

Comment: This is a really good answer that gets at the heart of something I've been trying to do for a few months now, which is get the text to the test file for code level text comparison.