# Using angular functions ($q) in protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I want to use the $q service of angular in my e2e tests. (I want to get the texts of a bunch of  elements via *getText()* which returns a promise. After all promises are resolved, I want to test the list. So I want to use *$q.all()* etc.)

`angular.injector(['myApp']).get('$q');` results in "ReferenceError: angular is not defined"

Installing angular via node and then `var angular = require("angularjs");` results in "Error: Cannot find module 'angular'"

Also, inserting a `browser.waitForAngular()` does not help there.

Using the `inject(function($q) {})` syntax has the same problem.

How can I use such angular functions in protractor?

---

edit:

Here's the very naive version of what I want to achieve

```
var collectEntries = function(containers) {
    var entries = {};
    containers.each(function (container) {
        var title = container.element(by.tagName('h2'));
        title.getText().then(function (text) {
            var key = getSomeKey();
            var entry = processEntry(text);
            entries[key] = entry;
        });
    });
    return entries;
};
```

That works in principle, at some point in time *entries* contains all data. However, I need to wait for that moment. What I would do is create and return a promise that gets resolved as soon as all *getText* promises are resolved.

e.g.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$q.all(getTextPromises).then(function () {
    deferred.resolve(entries);
});
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: your question looks similar to this [access list with protractor also used ng-model instead of getText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227195/how-to-access-input-at-item-level-in-protractor-by-model/27237425#27237425).In this example (angular promise..then) is used to check list on UI.Is this what are you looking for

Comment: @vijay, it uses _getValue_ instead of _getText_ and does something on each individual item (log it). What I want is to get the text of all items and THEN do something.

Comment: means you want json array list of your data . ?

Comment: I want a data structure which contains the results of all *getText()* calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of your code `containers` is a list of elementFinders? (i.e. `var containers = [element(by.x), element(by.y), element(by.z)]`):

Using q: (you need to add q as dependency in package.json first)

```
    var q = require('q');
    var collectEntries = function(containers) {
        var entries = {};
        containers.each(function (container) {
            var deferred = q.defer();
            var title = container.element(by.tagName('h2'));
            title.getText().then(function (text) {
                deferred.resolve(processEntry(text));
            });
            entries[getSomeKey()] = deferred.promise();
        });
        return q.all(entries);
    };

    expect(collectEntries).toBe({key1: 'title1', key2: 'title2'})
```

But protractor knows promise itself (and it's preferably that you don't mix protractor's promise with q promise unless you know what you're doing):

```
    var collectEntries = function(containers) {
        var entries = {};
        containers.each(function (container) {
            entries[getSomeKey()] = container.element(by.tagName('h2')).
                getText().then(function (text) {
                    return processEntry(text);
                });
        });
        return protractor.promise.fullyResolved(entries);
    };

    expect(collectEntries).toBe({key1: 'title1', key2: 'title2'})
```

If your `containers` are found using a single selector (i.e. `var containers = element.all(by.xyz)`), it's even easier:

```
    var collectEntries = function(containers) {
        return containers.reduce(function(entries, elem) {
          return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
            entries[getSomeKey()] = processEntry(text);
            return entries;
          });
        }, {});
    };

    expect(collectEntries).toBe({key1: 'title1', key2: 'title2'})
```

Comment: The solution using _reduce()_ is incredibly elegant and works like a charm, thanks so much, very good answer. It's like magic how protractor resolves all the promises (in _processEntry()_ I haven have more promises). Since we are working with promises I had to change your last line to `collectEntries(aSelector).then(function(entries) { expect... });`

Comment: Although, strictly speaking you have not answered the question :-) I tried requiring **q** as suggested, that works. However, I'm developing an angular app and angular already has $q. So it would be nice to use that. `require('angularjs')` (after installing it via npm) did not work for me. Any idea?

Comment: Your angular app and protractor are running in different environment (angular via browser and protractor via node), so no you won't be able to require the angular from your browser. I guess if you add angular as a dependency of protractor you can do it, but I don't know why you would want to do that just to access $q when you can simply require q.

Comment: `collectEntries(aSelector).then(function(entries) { expect... });` is not required if you're working with jasmine since protractor patched jasmine to expect promises.